# Remove items from ListView with a custom adapter 

Tags: android, android-listview, customization, adapter

I have a custom `ListView` and adapter. I can delete an item from my lists which are set on my custom list, but I can delete from `ListView`. When I try to call `adapter.remove(position)` the editor is saying to "create a method `"remove(int position)""`. I don't know what should I do when I create this method into the adapter. Code :

**Filling my listview:**

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        LayoutInflater mLInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), kimdenlist, konulist,
                mLInflater);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**ListViewAdapter:**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> cartItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> kimdenlist; // to load images
    ArrayList<String> konulist; // for data
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> kimdenlist, ArrayList<String> konulist,
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
        mContext = context;
        this.kimdenlist = kimdenlist;
        this.konulist = konulist;
        mLayoutInflater = layoutInflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {

        return kimdenlist.size(); // images array length
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;

    // customized Listview
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v;
        final int pos = position;
        v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listust, null);

        TextView kimden = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textvKimden);
        kimden.setText(kimdenlist.get(position));
        TextView konu = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textvKonu);
        konu.setText(konulist.get(position));
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chk);
        try {
            if (count != 0) {
                boolean b = cartItems.get(pos);
                if (b == false)
                    ch.setChecked(false);
                else
                    ch.setChecked(true);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }


        ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                cartItems.put(pos, arg1);
                count++;

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> getcartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

}
```

**When I click to "delete_Button" : I can only remove from lists:**

```
konulist.remove(konulist.get(position));;
kimdenlist.remove(kimdenlist.get(position));
```

Answer (score 12):

It's because your listViewAdapter has not remove method! You extend BaseAdapter and it has not remove method. You shoud create remove method in listviewAdapter and it will looks like

```
public void remove(int position){
    konulist.remove(konulist.get(position));;
    kimdenlist.remove(kimdenlist.get(position));
}
```

You have to understand how list view and adapter works. Adapter holds data for listview. Adapter method getView is called when list line is going to be created. List size is calculated by value returned by adapter's getCount() and so on...

Comment: I am already doing this. My list's item are deleted but my listview's item is not delete. For instance; I click the position=0 and position zero has "A11" for konulist, "A1" for kimdenlist. And position=1 has "B11" for konulist, "B1" for kimdenlist. And they listed on listview . When I delete the position=0 and then get back to the listview--> position=0 still there! BUT (as I continue to process) I click the position=0 it is show me position=1's data.

Comment: @Merve Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you delete an item.

Comment: It didnt change the situation

Answer (score 1):

To remove an item from ListView BUT NOT INSIDE ADAPTER CLASS:

```
lv.removeViewAt(index);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where "index" specifies the position or index in the ListView that holds the item to delete.

To remove an item from ListView INSIDE ADAPTER CLASS: First you need to add a Tag to each item in the list. use some layout within the content item in the list to assign that Tag. This can be done within the method getView ().

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    row = convertView;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_lugares_visitar, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // ... DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE
        holder.linearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.ll_container);
        // Set the position as a Tag for the view
        holder.linearLayoutContainer.setTag(position);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    // ... DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE

    return row;
}

// Method for remove an item of ListView inside adapter class
// you need to pass as an argument the tag you added to the layout of your choice
public void removeView(Object position) {
      // lv and the adapter must be public-static in their Activity Class
      SomeActivity.lv.removeViewAt(Integer.parteInt(position).toString());
      SomeActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your  code

`konulist.remove(konulist.get(position));
kimdenlist.remove(kimdenlist.get(position));`

you can call the method:

`notifyDataSetChanged();`